# How to sort the select2 (jQuery plugin) options alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to sort the [select2](https://select2.org/) options in alphabetical order. I have the following code and would like to know, how can this be achieved:

```
<select name="list" id="mylist" style="width:140px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>    
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>


$('#mylist').select2({
  sortResults: function(results) { return results.sort(); } 
});
```

I want to sort the data via 'text'.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Select2 API v3.x (`sortResults`)

You can sort elements using `sortResults` callback option with [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare):

```js
$( '#mylist' ).select2({
  /* Sort data using localeCompare */
  sortResults: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" integrity="sha256-ijlUKKj3hJCiiT2HWo1kqkI79NTEYpzOsw5Rs3k42dI=" crossorigin="anonymous" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-7A2MDY2eGSSUvgfbuH1IdzYk8qkEd3uzwiXADqPDdtY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="list" id="mylist" style="width:140px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>    
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

## Select2 [API v4.0 (`sorter`)](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api)

You can sort elements using `sorter` callback option:

```js
$('#mylist').select2({
    sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" integrity="sha256-xqxV4FDj5tslOz6MV13pdnXgf63lJwViadn//ciKmIs=" crossorigin="anonymous" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-FA14tBI8v+/1BtcH9XtJpcNbComBEpdawUZA6BPXRVw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="list" id="mylist" style="width:140px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>    
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

---

## Without jQuery

I had another general purpose approach (you can use value or an attribute for sorting elements) without using jQuery:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("mylist");
var options = [];
// Get elements to sort
document.querySelectorAll('#mylist > option').forEach(
  option => options.push(option)
);
// Empty select
while (select.firstChild) {
    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
}
// Sort array using innerText (of each option node)
options.sort(
  (a, b) => a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText)
);
// Add the nodes again in order
for (var i in options) {
    select.appendChild(options[i]);
}
```

```html
<select name="list" id="mylist" style="width:140px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>    
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

## With jQuery

Thanks [@Narendra Sisodia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899618/narendrasingh-sisodia) for jQuery tip:

```js
/* Get options */
var selectList = $('#mylist > option');
/* Order by innerText (case insensitive) */
selectList.sort(
  (a, b) => a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText)
);
/* Re-do select HTML */
$('#mylist').html(selectList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="list" id="mylist" style="width:140px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>    
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the selection order in which the values were selected without sorting the the list?

Comment: Are you talking about keeping the original unmodified and an orderly copy?

Comment: @BalakrishnanBsk, which of the solutions did not work for you? What exact version of jquery and internet explorer do you use? Did you use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag? Please, add more information.

Answer (score 5):

Select2 version 4.0 has renamed `sortResults` to `sorter`, so you can do:

```
$('#input').select2({
    sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort();
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't sort the initial list, if it's not given in alphabetical order. Plus, I believe you need to give sort a function as parameter that will do the comparison, as @OscarGarcia has done.

Comment: On https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3195#issuecomment-256938416 there is a more detailed version which sorts alphabetically and which works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this code:

```
$('#your_select').select2({
     /* Sort data using lowercase comparison */
     sorter: data => data.sort((a,b) => a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase() ? 0 : -1)

});
```

I hope it has been helped you! =)

Answer (score 1):

This was taken from the github issue, so all credit goes to the original poster, but this is what worked for me.

**Version 4.x**

```
$( '#mylist' ).select2({
  sorter: function(data) {
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.text > b.text) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.text < b.text) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
  }
});
```