# jQuery Select2 sorting numbers

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-select2

i have dropdown boxes with jQuery and Select2 but when there are numbers i want them differently sorted:

**This is how it is now**:

[image]

**Want it like this**:

- 3
- 4.5
- 24
- 28
- 35
- 42

So that the user will get first the small numbers and then the bigger ones. How can you do that with Select2? I am running Select2 v4.0.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort the select2( plugin ) options alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762180/how-to-sort-the-select2-plugin-options-alphabetically)

Comment: @Refilon Tryed that one already... didnt work for me.

Comment: @Maanstraat The answer *is* on that linked question, but it's not just a copy-paste solution. The answer there shows how to add a sorting function to your select box, all you need to do is change the function body so that it sorts by numeric value instead of string value.